# Using VPN in a Cloud9 workspace

Tags: vpn, cloud9-ide

Good afternoon,

Is it possible to connect to a (Cisco) VPN within a Cloud9 workspace?

One of the projects I'm working on requires connecting to SAP web service provided on the clients closed network, a Cisco dial-in account has been set up to enable me to do this (which works fine from my regular desktop).

Within cloud9 I can install vpnc, but running it gives an error,

```
sudo vpnc
vpnc: can't initialise tunnel interface: Operation not permitted
```

Is it just something which isn't supported (atm) in c9?  Is it available on Premium accounts?  Finally, any suggestions on whether a workaround is possible?

Regards,
Ryan

Comment: Quite sure this is not possible.

Comment: I created a ticket for this same issue with Cloud9 themselves. At least initially, the employees response was that Cloud9 DOES allow VPN clients to run on their hosted workspaces. However, my experience has me running to the same dead end as you: (Operation not permitted). https://community.c9.io/t/can-i-run-a-vpn-on-my-cloud9-project/18491/2

Answer (score 1):

For security reasons Cloud9 can't allow creating network interfaces in hosted containers. For this to work I'd suggest to use a setup with an external VPN as workspace https://c9.io/site/blog/2014/09/digitalocean/.

Comment: Unfortunately (at the moment) the instructions in that video are not working (unable to SSH into the digital ocean droplet).  A quick search shows a number of other people having similar issues - which is a shame, as it looked like a really nice workflow.

Comment: Thanks-- what is the purpose of using Cloud9 in this solution at all however? Aren't you suggesting digitalocean to have your code, run your code, and run the VPN? I suppose Cloud9 would be my virtual IDE into that code, but it's little more than just making a Cloud9 version of the interface I could just use directly on digitalocean, right? I'm not much familiar with digitalocean so please correct me if I'm wrong.